# Why are there two options to read a CSV file in PySpark? Which one should I use?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

Spark 2.4.4:

I want to import a CSV file, but there are two options. Why is that? And which one is better? Which one should I use?

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local[2]") \
    .config('spark.cores.max', '3') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '2g') \
    .config('spark.executor.cores', '2') \
    .config('spark.driver.memory','1g') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

## Option 1

```py
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("data/myfile.csv")
```

## Option 2

```py
df = spark.read.load("data/myfile.csv", format="csv", inferSchema="true", header="true")
```

Comment: They both do the same thing

Comment: And there's a third option `spark.read.csv("data/myfile.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)`

Comment: Thanks! Why so many ways to do the same thing?
Also another question: Python has the same syntax as Scala? For example when calling a function. For example here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html
When I switch between Scala and Python it's always basically the same code.

Comment: Just the way they wrote it... And no, Python doesn't have the same syntax,. For example, if you `.map()` over a dataframe

Comment: But like 90-95% is the same? Could you explain why the syntax to call the `.map()` function is different? For example here: https://spark.apache.org/examples.html
The syntax there is the same for both Python and Scala: `textFile.flatMap(...).map(...).reduceByKey(...)`
Or do you mean `rdd.map()`?

Comment: Scala lambda functions are different than Python. Python doesn't use the arrows, for example. And scala uses brackets instead of indentation, and you have direct access to Java libraries in Scala

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that's not what I meant. I mean the pyspark functions that you want to call. It's both in Scala and Python the same syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spark 2, `com.databricks.spark.csv` isn't necessary to write out completely since the CSV reader is included. Therefore option 2 would be preferred.

Or slightly shorter,

```
spark.read.csv("data/myfile.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)
```

But option 2 would be better if you extracted the input format into some configuration file

Answer (score 1):

In all languages (weather programming or conversational), there are always several different means to the same end.

Options while reading CSV file

```
Spark CSV dataset provides multiple options to work with CSV files, all these options 
delimiter

delimiter option is used to specify the column delimiter of the CSV file. By default, it is comma (,) character, but can be set to any character us this option.


val df2 = spark.read.options(Map("delimiter"->","))
  .csv("src/main/resources/zipcodes.csv")

inferSchema

The default value set to this option is false, when set to true it automatically infer column types based on the data. It requires to read the data one more time to infer the schema.


val df2 = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->","))
  .csv("src/main/resources/zipcodes.csv")

header

This option is used to read the first line of the CSV file as column names. By default the value of this option is false , and all column types are assumed to be a string.


val df2 = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->",","header"->"true"))
  .csv("src/main/resources/zipcodes.csv")

quotes

When you have a column with a delimiter that used to split the columns, use quotes option to specify the quote character, by default it is ” and delimiters inside quotes are ignored. but using this option you can set any character.
nullValues

Using nullValues option you can specify the string in a CSV to consider as null. For example, if you want to consider a date column with a value “1900-01-01” set null on DataFrame.
dateFormat

dateFormat option to used to set the format of the input DateType and TimestampType columns. Supports all java.text.SimpleDateFormat formats.

Note: Besides the above options, Spark CSV dataset also supports many other options, please refer to this article for details.
```

Reading CSV files with a user-specified custom schema

```
If you know the schema of the file ahead and do not want to use the inferSchema option for column names and types, use user-defined custom column names and type using schema option.


    val schema = new StructType()
      .add("RecordNumber",IntegerType,true)
      .add("Zipcode",IntegerType,true)
      .add("City",StringType,true)
      .add("State",StringType,true)
      .add("Notes",StringType,true)
    val df_with_schema = spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .schema(schema)
      .load("src/main/resources/zipcodes.csv")
    df_with_schema.printSchema()
    df_with_schema.show(false)
```

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-csv-file-into-dataframe/